# Unable to access <ip _ address>\myintranet

Tags: xampp, lan, intranet

192.168.1.123\wordpresssite works fine, whether PC is awake or in sleep mode.

192.168.1.123\myintranet (a vanilla php-html thing) is only available when the host PC is awake.

Both sites are in C:\XAMPP\htdocs

Why the difference in accessibility?
How do I make \myintranet available, whatever state the host PC is in?

Comment: are you sure the wordpresssite isn't cached and thus available offline? A server that isn't awake shouldn't be able to respond on application layer as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Glad someone's awake! Thank you. :)